# MATLAB special characters/operators

Tags: matlab

I am new to MATLAB and have difficulties understanding the following line of code:

```
ef   = sum(X.*(A*X), 1)';
```

What is the semantics of the dot (`.`) in front of the multiplication operator, and the apostrophe (`'`) after the right parenthesis?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f0-40063.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `'` means transpose: `A'` is the same than `transpose(A)`

and `.*` is an element-wise multiplication. (`*` is a matrix multiplication )